# Why redirect prevent the duplicate transaction in PRG pattern

Tags: http, redirect

I am learning about Post-Redirect-Get pattern. but I cant understand, why redirect to the original page prevent the duplicate transaction if we refresh the?
could you please tell me why?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it my friends :)
returning a status code that indicates a new location for the result, for example 303 ("See other") or 302("Found"/"Moved temporarily"), the latter of which is used most often nowadays. Together with the 30x result code a Location header is sent which contains the URL of the page to which the request is redirected. Only the headers are sent, no body is included.